# Automatically change image after few seconds

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to javascript and I was wondering if it would be possible to have javascript automtically change the image after few seconds, this is my college project and it can be very messy. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>titleHere</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/menu.css">
    <script>
        function changeImage(imageName){
            var pickImage = document.getElementById("mainImg");
            pickImage.src = imageName;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page_container">

        <div class="menu">
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <nav id="cssmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html"><span>HOME</span></a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#"><span>GALLERY</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>CONTACT</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="resortTitle"><center>The Reves Recours</center></div>
        <div class="thumbnails" align="center">
            <img src="../images/resort1.jpg" onmouseover="changeImage('../images/resort1.jpg')" alt="Missing Image"/>
            <img src="../images/resort2.jpg" onmouseover="changeImage('../images/resort2.jpg')" alt="Missing Image"/>
            <img src="../images/resort3.jpg" onmouseover="changeImage('../images/resort3.jpg')" alt="Missing Image"/>
            <img src="../images/resort4.jpg" onmouseover="changeImage('../images/resort4.jpg')" alt="Missing Image"/>
        </div>
        <div class="preview" align="center">
            <img src="../images/resortLogoLarge.png" id="mainImg">
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnails" align="center">
            <img src="../images/resort5.jpg" onmouseover="changeImage('../images/resort5.jpg')" alt="Missing Image"/>
            <img src="../images/resort6.jpg" onmouseover="changeImage('../images/resort6.jpg')" alt="Missing Image"/>
            <img src="../images/resort7.jpg" onmouseover="changeImage('../images/resort7.jpg')" alt="Missing Image"/>
            <img src="../images/resort8.jpg" onmouseover="changeImage('../images/resort8.jpg')" alt="Missing Image"/>
        </div>
        <div class="greybar"></div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="watmark"> Created by: ---</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
window.onload=function(){
    setInterval(function(){changeName("yourImageName")},2000) //2 seconds
}
```

to the beginning of the `<script>`. It will change your image after 2 seconds pass.

Comment: So that would change it to the image I set instead of "yourImageName", but what would I do if wanted it to change to next image that is in "thumbnails"?

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = ['src1','src2','src3'],i=0;
setTimeout(function(){
    changeImage(images[i]);
    i++;
    if(i>images.length)
    i=0;
},3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the array of list of images you have and then loop thorugh for the delay as you would required using various solutions available for delay like using setInterval on Window load etc.